# Web socket in aws lambda api gateway handle huge data

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, aws-lambda

i am using the AWS API gateway and build type as Websocket
and using data storage as RDS
i have configured the setting in the api gateway and written functions for the connect , disconnect and default

i have a table which contains millions of data ,i want to return this data in the response,
but my websocket is working perfectly upto 1000 documents. if i increase the size i am not getting the any data at **client side or CLI**

using the command  : websocat  wss://{id}.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev

```
data Source: RDS(MySql)

websocket: aws api gateway(web socket) python

client: Angular(Receiver)
```

```
# lambda with api gateway
import json
from data_lib import db_operations

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    try:
        data = db_operations.co_ordinates_data()
        # [{"x":231,"y":443.33,"type":"co-ordinates"}..{}..]
        print("data: received:{0}".format(data))
        return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(data)
    }
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

# db_operations data query 
def proximity_data():
    try:
        conn = connect_to_db()
        cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        query = "select * from `co_ordinates_data`;"
        cursor.execute(query)
        data= cursor.fetchall()
        print("fetch data:",len(data)) # 13,9073
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        print("connection and cursor are closed .")
        return data[1:1000]

    except Exception as err:
        print("fetching the data:{0}".format(err))
        raise err
```

can any one help on this

Comment: How exactly are you sending what from where to where?

Comment: @deceze , from RDS(Mysql) data as websocket to Angular dashboard

Comment: So you're dumping 1000+ result rows into one websocket message…? That's probably too large and you need to split that up into multiple messages.

Comment: websocket is a one time job right . is there anyway that we can poll, like pagination in  normal api's for splitting the data

Comment: You'd just send several small messages instead of one large message? Note that sockets aren't a "request-response" mechanism to begin with, they're meant for *events*. You can layer a request-response or "poll" protocol on top of that if you have to, e.g. [WAMP](https://wamp-proto.org).

Comment: Previously i am using the Flask with socket.io and there i am able to send the data , but right now we are migrating the micro-services to serverless. Based on your suggesition i think we need use the Messaging brokers. through the loop i need to add the all the data into the queue   .. (Aws IOT core/Kafka)

Comment: You may want to look at the payload size for API Gateway websockets: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#apigateway-execution-service-websocket-limits-table